# Excel: Function to replace variable name

Tags: excel

Before I begin this question, I would like to state that I have read a few articles, I have tried a couple of functions (=REPLACE, =SUBSTITUTE) but I'm not able to get the results required, I'm new to Excel.

The following is a homework question.

> Question: Use appropriate text functions to shorten the variable names to something like Arizona Females Young, Arizona Females Old, and Arizona Females All, also is there a way to do it automatically for all variables in 1 function. The screenshot is attached.

[image: Excel Variables Sample]

Comment: What have you tried? What are the variables you're trying to replace? Can you clarify please.

Comment: @BruceWayne, i'm sorry I dont mean to sound rude, but as stated in the question I have tried (=REPLACE and =Substitute), I'm trying to replace the first row (variables with the ones like in the question).

Comment: It seems you don't need a function but "Find and Replace". Replace "Licensed Drivers" with nothing. Replace "19 and Under #" with "Young". Replace "85 and Over #" with "Old".

Comment: Hi @NareshBhople, thanks for your comment unfortunately the Prof wants us to use a function.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This table looks like it was produced as the result of Power Query?  Perhaps your assignment is referring to Power Query text functions.  If so, you should be looking at the Power Query Text Function pages.

Comment: Is your homework expecting this to be done with [Excel Functions](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332), [PowerQuery Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-replace), or [VBA Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function)?

Answer (score 0):

If you need change headers:

- Licensed Drivers Alabama Female 19 and under # -> Female 19 and under #
- Licensed Drivers Alabama Female 19 and under # -> Female 85 and over #

function "Find and Replace" is the best solution.

You also can extract value to other place by formulas:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Licensed Drivers Alabama ","") 
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,"Licensed Drivers Alabama ","")
```